# To whom does this babby belong?

Tags: support, ios-app

In the change list for the iOS app there is an interesting new feature: a babby!

> [image: change list]

I guess a member of the development team became a parent, but who?

> [image: babby]

Oh, and yes: ***congratulations!***

Comment: I was just about to correct the "babby" typo... but later saw the screenshot...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: I took the original link from the iOS landing page. Not sure if I am allowed to share it.

Comment: ah ok @Patrick  :(

Comment: This baby is going to be a great iOS developer! ;)

Comment: Until he turns 13, starts dressing all in black, gets way too many piercings and starts experimenting with Android.

Comment: @Shog9 or even worse, BlackBerry.

Comment: That is gone at the time he is 13.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel) welcomed a [new babby to the family](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3512901#3512901) in the [beginning of June](https://twitter.com/kerrick/status/605590808838860801), so my money's on <del>blaming</del> congratulating him.

Comment: Had babby, can confirm.

Comment: how is babby formed?

Comment: @Jin [tag:status-canrepro]

Comment: Boffo babby, Brian.